# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server Multicraft

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos

I am having a lot of issues - #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I have just downloaded and installed MultiCraft on my servers. I used to use phpMyAdmin and it used to work perfect. Anyways, MultiCraft is creating the user correctly although when I am going to go and login it with the details that it has provided it does not work it brings this error up - #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Now, I started to dig around so I went into phpMyAdmin on the root account and I saw that the account has been created, and as the host it was % I changed it to localhost and it started working. Now, if I was to do this for every customer they would have to wait for me to do this and It would be a bit time consuming for them, why is phpMyAdmin not allowing people onto the server with % as the host.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, there are two main means of connecting to the server: via UNIX Sockets or TCP/IP networking. `%` is a wildcard operator for the hostname but does not apply to sockets. When connecting to `localhost`, it uses a socket connection (yes, I know that in general networking terms, "localhost" is mapped to 127.0.0.1, but MySQL has to be a bit different).

So if you create (or MultiCraft creates) new users `foo@localhost` and `bar@%`, "foo" can only connect via sockets and "bar" can only connect via TCP/IP. You should figure out how your application is connecting to MySQL and standardize on that method. That's why the MySQL installation defaults to users root@localhost and root@127.0.0.1, so you can connect from either method.

A few notes:

- I don't know anything about MultiCraft, but I'd be surprised if it's actually creating a new user in MySQL for each user account. That's...an awkward way of doing things. Generally an application creates one or a few MySQL accounts for the program to use. That MySQL account has nothing to do with the users who actually have accounts on your application; instead the application has tables that handle user permissions within the application. For instance, in my WordPress instance, there's one MySQL user account which WordPress uses to talk to MySQL. Within the WordPress database, there's a table that contains about 800 entries for individual user accounts. So all I'm saying is that you might not need to make this change for each individual user.
- By changing your root account from % to localhost, I'm a bit surprised that you weren't kicked out of phpMyAdmin. Likewise I'm also a bit surprised that there weren't already two root accounts.

Anyway, hope that's given you enough information to figure out what's going on. Always remember to make a backup before making changes. Good luck.